# How to get rid off animation glitch when navigating to another view in SwiftUI

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui

When navigation to a view containing a list in SwiftUI there is an animation glitch both in the simulator and on a real device. Just when the navigation animation ends the list items seem to "jump" a few pixels to their designated positions.
See the following simple example:

[image: animation glitch]

**ContentView**

```
struct ContentView: View {
    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            List {
                NavigationLink(destination: SubView()) {
                    Text("To the List")
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**SubView**

```
struct SubView: View {
    @State private var labels = ["One", "Two", "Three", "Four"]
    var body: some View {
        List {
            ForEach(labels, id: \.self) { label in
                Text(label)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Has anyone else experienced this behaviour?
How do I get rid of it?

**Update:** 
The glitch does not appear using a static list without ForEach.

Comment: This kind of jump is pretty common with List and Form right now, and is almost certainly a bug. I recommend filing feedback with Apple: http://feedbackassistant.apple.com

Comment: Please find solution posted in similar topic [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59840861/12299030)